# Customize chances of picking element randomly

Tags: javascript, math, random, probability

I have two defined objects: `x` and `y`
If I do following, chances of getting either `x` or `y` are equal – 1 of **2**:

```
var primary = [x, y];
var secondary = primary[Math.floor(Math.random() * primary.length)];
```

This would take a 1 of **3** (smaller) chances of getting `y`:

```
var primary = [x, x, y];
// secondary unchanged
```

etc.

But I believe, this is bad practice because if I'd wanted to set infinitesimal chances (e.g. 1 of **1e9**) of getting `y`, I would have to do something *extremely* wasteful like this:

```
var primary = new Array();
for (i = 1e9 - 1; i--; i) primary.push(x);
primary.push(y);
var secondary = primary[Math.floor(Math.random() * primary.length)];
```

Is there a better way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Just "round" your random number so that you fall on one index with a higher probability than on another. There is no reason to build a huge array for this.

Comment: @Bergi: Sorry, I didn't understand you.

Comment: Just use `primary[Math.random < 1e-9 ? 1 : 0]`. There's no reason to actually create the array when you know which elements will be where - just select the elements by their imaginary position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without digging too much into ECMAScript specification and its actual implementations, `Math.random()` appears to produce a number from the range `0..1` in a smooth fashion. This means that the number is 50% likely to be less than `0.5`, 25% likely to be less than `0.25`, 10% likely to be less than `0.1`, etc.

To get `x` 17% of the time (and, conversely, `y` 83% of the time), one could use the corresponding number to be a gateway for `Math.random()`’s results:

```js
const x = "x";
const y = "y";

function getRandom() {
  return Math.random() < 0.17 ? x : y;
}

const value = getRandom();
// 17% "x", 83% "y"
```

This works fine for two values, but working with lists of 3+ elements would require different thinking.